# Count the number of raster cells of each land use type in neighborhood

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, focal-statistics

I have a raster about different land use types(5 types),each raster cell has a categorical value(1-5). ArcGIS Focal Statistics can calculate mean, range, and even variety of each processing cell, but I want to count the number of  each land use type for the processing cell in the neighborhood area.

[image]

For example,the processing cell in pic has 3 land use type1, 2 type2, 2 type3, 1 type4 and 1 type5. (Neighborhood: 3*3 rectangle),how can I do this?

Comment: Have you checked - http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/summarize-within.htm - Summarize within tool? Also, if you are comfortable with R, I have an alternative solution for the same

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in two steps:

1. calculate `10^(value-1)` in the `Raster calculator`;
2. then the `Sum` in `Focal Statistics`.

The output values will be between 0 (0 cells of any types in the neighbourhood area) and 90000 (9 cells of type 5 in the neighbourhood area) and their sum of the digits can be between 0 (no cell) and 9 (all the cells). 
For instance, the output of your illustrated example will be 11223, which stands for (reading from left to right) 1 cell of type 5, 1 of type 4, 2 of type 3, 2 of type 2 and finally 3 of type 1.

Comment: +1 It looks incredible but, it is true!

Comment: Thx,the method is useful!

Answer (score 2):

Reclassify the data so that all the values from 1 - 4 equal 0, reclassify the 5 values to 1.  Run focal statistics using sum.  The resulting raster will have the total number of 5 values within your roving window.  Repeat four more times for the other values.